# Add SSL to AWS elastic beanstalk public DNS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying django4 on AWS elastic beanstalk(EB), and currently trying to add SSL to the public domain provided by AWS.

Is it actually possible to add SSL to EB's public domain? I know that certbot requires domain name, but does EB's public domain considered good enough?

I tried to use certbot but it failed. Has anybody tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does EB's public domain considered good enough?

Sadly, its not enough, because this domain belongs to AWS, not you. You can only get valid public SSL certificates for domains that **you own** or at least control. This means, that you can't get SSL cert for EB default domain.

You can add [CloudFront in front of your EB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudfront.html) and this will give you https endpoint. But all traffic between CloudFront and EB will be http (not https), because again you do not have valid SSL certificate for EB.

Comment: Understood, so only if I bought my own domain I'll have a valid SSL certificate. Thanks. About the CloudFront what does it really do?

Comment: @azimrose Someone else can own the domain. The point is that you must be able to control it and add ssl validation records to it. CF is Cache, basically CDN from AWS.